# Ansible looping through files

Tags: loops, plugins, ansible, ansible-2.x

Prior to Ansible 2.5, the syntax for loops used to be `with_x`. Starting at 2.5, `loop` is favored and `with_x` basically disappeared from the docs.

Still, the docs mention exemples of how to replace `with_x` with `loop`. But I'm clueless as to how we're now supposed to loop through a directory of files.

Let's say I need to upload all the files within a given dir, I used to use `with_fileglob`.

```
- name: Install local checks
  copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: /etc/sensu/plugins/
    owner: sensu
    group: sensu
    mode: 0744
  with_fileglob:
    - plugins/*
```

So what's the modern equivalent? Is it even possible? I know I still can use `with_fileglob` but as I'm writing new roles, I'd better have them future-proof.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

- The equivalent is below. See [Comparing loop and with_*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#comparing-loop-and-with)

```yaml
  loop: "{{ lookup('fileglob', 'plugins/*', wantlist=True) }}"
```

- Optionally, you can use *query* instead of *lookup*. Quoting from [Forcing lookups to return lists](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#forcing-lookups-to-return-lists-query-and-wantlist-true):

> The difference between *lookup* and *query* is largely that *query* will always return a list. The default behavior of *lookup* is to return a string of comma-separated values. *lookup* can be explicitly configured to return a list using *wantlist=True*.

```yaml
  loop: "{{ query('fileglob', 'plugins/*') }}"
```

- Additionally, *q* was introduced as a short form of *query*

```yaml
  loop: "{{ q('fileglob', 'plugins/*') }}"
```

All three options give the same result. See [Lookup plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html).

Comment: It works perfectly! I couldn't find this in the docs and thought it had been removed as every with_x alternative is presented but this one. Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

From the current [Ansible loops doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html):

> Any `with_*` statement that requires using `lookup` within a loop should
>   not be converted to use the `loop` keyword. For example, instead of
>   doing:
>
> `loop: "{{ lookup('fileglob', '*.txt', wantlist=True) }}"`
>
> it’s cleaner to keep:
>
> `with_fileglob: '*.txt'`

Comment: Well, this is very important to know, while technically it is not the answer to OP, this is a great practical suggestion, so upvoting.